# What is meant by AT/cm in transformer?

Tags: transformer, electromagnetism, electric-machine, magnetic-flux

In a problem related to transformer loss I have found a line "AT/cm for a flux density of 1.2 Wb/m^2 in iron to be 5"

I've searched in google for 30 minutes about what is AT and how it is related to transformer losses and found nothing.

Comment: amp-turns/cm is a metric of magnetic strength

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\$ H \$ is the magnetic field strength and is calculated as:

\$ H = \dfrac{N \cdot I}{l} \$  where \$ N \$ is turns,. \$ I \$ is current and \$ l \$ is magnetic path length.

In SI units it is measured in \$ \text{amp} \cdot \text{meter}^{-1} \$ though you often see \$ \text{amp} \cdot \text{turn} \cdot \text{meter}^{-1} \$.  The turn however is not a unit so should not be included.

\$ H \$ is related to flux density \$ B \$ measured in tesla by the permiability \$ \mu \$, \$  B = \mu \cdot H \$.  Permiability is not linear for a lot of materials so you will often see a B-H curve published.  Free space does have a linear permiability however and some magnetic components have an air gap to make use of it.

AT is used for ampere turns \$ N \cdot I \$

Answer (score 2):

AT/cm is a measure of the H-field acting on the core material of an inductor.

Take the length of the magnetic circuit, and the number of turns enclosed in that path. AT/cm is the current in one turn, multiplied by the number of turns, divided by the magnetic path length in cm.